# Angularjs to pass multiple params

Tags: angularjs

I want to update status information for which I need to pass two params one is say school_id and other one is status which may be(approved, pending , declined) depending on the user clicks the button. I have a table like school_info with fields like **id** **school_name**  **status** So in my applicationjs I need to pass two params id and status. here is my html code, I have ng-repeat so I am using school in schools.

```
<a href="#/changeStatus/{{school.id}}/approved"><button class="btn btn-success" ng-model="approve">Approve</button></a>
<a href="#/changeStatus/{{school.id}}/declined"><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-model="decline">Decline</button><a>
<a href="#/changeStatus/{{school.id}}/pending"><button class="btn btn-deafult" ng-model="Pending">Pending</button></a>
```

my app.js code is

```
var app=angular.module("admin",[]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'home.php',
      controller: 'adminCtrl'
    }).when('/changeStatus/:id/:sts',{
      templateUrl:'home.php',
      controller:'adminCtrl'
    }).when('/Mapview/:id',{
      templateUrl:'mapview.html',
      controller:'MapCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/"
    });
});
app.controller("adminCtrl",function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
   var sts=$routeParams.status;
   var id=$routeParams.id;
   console.log("sts"+sts+id);
   //here I want two params to be fetched inside console log. when clicked on specific btn.I have seen previous questions asked on multiple params passing but there must be easy way out to get multiple params.
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `ng-href` instead of `href`
and your hrefs should be like as below, no need of `:`

```
<a ng-href="#/changeStatus/{{school.id}}/approved"><button class="bt......
<a ng-href="#/changeStatus/{{school.id}}/declined"><button class="btn btn...
```

then in the controller,

```
    var sts=$routeParams.sts;   // u need to get as sts , 
   //because you get it as sts in .when('/changeStatus/:id/:sts'..                          
    var id=$routeParams.id;
    console.log("sts"+sts);
    console.log("id"+id);
```

Comment: How about getting values in appjs Is my code write for getting multiple params?

Comment: Yes correct Good one, but why to use ng-href I am getting with normal href

Comment: glad to help you, and note that use `ng-href` because `{{school.id}}` bind little time after the page renders. but there can have a situation when u clicking on the link `{{school.id}}` may not be ready, then your link is not working as u expected. using `ng-href` u can avoid that issue.

Comment: cheerz. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Your links are not correct.

In AngularJS docs, they have this example:

```
// Given:
// URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
// Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
//
// Then
$routeParams ==> {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}
```

I didnt test it, but I think the only change you need to do is to remove the double-dots from your links, like this:

```
<a href="#/changeStatus/{{school.id}}/approved">
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-model="approve">Approve</button>
</a>
```

And also, you have a mistake in your controller. You named the params 'id' and 'sts', but then you use 'id' and 'status'.

Comment: Sorry by mistake I put there insted of putting them in app code.